# Mailchimp extension menu items are missing

Tags: menu, mailchimp

I've installed the Mailchimp extension (v.2.0.1 downloaded directly from https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp) in CiviCRM v.5.1 (running WordPress 5.2) but the Mailchimp menu items do not get added to the CiviCRM menu. How can I troubleshoot and fix this?

I *can* manually navigate to the Mailchimp extension configuration pages (such as https://mynonprofit.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fmailchimp%2Fsettings&reset=1). I've also tested and verified that the Mailchimp extension itself *is* working.

I've also tried manually adding the Mailchimp pages to the Civi menu (via "*Administer...  Customize Data and Screens... Navigation Menu*"). I found that I *can* add `civicrm/mailchimp/pull` to the menu system, but when I add `civicrm/mailchimp/pull&reset=1` to the menu, it results in an invalid menu URL ending in `...&q=civicrm%2Fmailchimp%2Fpull_reset_1`. The final `pull_reset_1` part is invalid. Since the `&reset=1` seems to be important for WordPress, omitting it is not a good workaround.

I've tried disabling and reenabling the extension, and completely uninstalling and reinstalling it, but the menu items do not appear. When installing it, the PHP error log file does not log any errors, so I'm puzzled even how to debug this. Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: are you talking about the sync functions? I usually access those via the scheduled jobs admin page

Comment: No... I'm talking about the menu items defined in the uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/xml/Menu/Mailchimp.xml file and referenced in the README.md file. For example, the "Mailings >> Mailchimp Settings" screen is where you configure the Mailchimp API key and Security Key.